# Splitting hardware dependant class in C++

Tags: c++, embedded, factory

I wanted to ask Your opinion about the best way of splitting hardware dependant code in C++.
Currently I have a class that's implementing an interface for temperature sensor that uses #ifdef:

```
class TemperatureSensor : public TemperatureI
{
TemperatureSensor()
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
/* Platform A dependant code */
#elsif PLATFORM_B
/* Platform B dependant code */
#endif
}

~TemperatureSensor()
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
/* Platform A dependant code */
#elsif PLATFORM_B
/* Platform B dependant code */
#endif
}

int getTemp()
{
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
/* Platform A dependant code */
#elsif PLATFORM_B
/* Platform B dependant code */
#endif
}
};
```

There are of course a couple of methods and more than 1 line of hardware dependant code.

Now what I want is:

1. Remove ifdefs from the code all together or if not possible limit it to one place
2. Move decision on creating the right implementation to compile time (using CMakeLists.txt)
3. Have as little boiler plate code as possible (there could be a helper class as I intend to use this solution in more than one place, but each place should have a minimum overhead)

One solution is to use a PIMPL and a factory, but unfortunately this results in a plethora of files and a lot of indirection.

- TemperatureSensor.cpp
- TemperatureSensor.hpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformFactory.hpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformA.cpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformA.hpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformAFactory.cpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformB.cpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformB.hpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformBFactory.cpp

And the following code:

```
class TemperatureSensor : public TemperatureI
{
TemperatureSensor() :
pImpl(TemperatureSensorFactory.create())
{}

int getTemp()
{
return pImpl.getTemp();
}
};
```

Do You have any better ideas?

Comment: You could conditionally compile the _entire_ `TemperatureSensor` class (possibly with different names to avoid confusion and allow both sensors in one program, and a typedef to map `TemperatureSensor` to the correct class).  How much code commonality is shared between the different sensor types?

Comment: Of course, the best approach depends on the nature of your overall design and intent, which isn't articulated too clearly. Does the term "hardware dependent" code relate to supporting different temperature sensors or different platforms using the same temperature sensor?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to put platform specific code in separate implementation files:

- TemperatureSensorPlatformA.cpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformA.hpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformB.cpp
- TemperatureSensorPlatformB.hpp

Then in TemperatureSensor.hpp you have:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
    #include "TemperatureSensorPlatformA.hpp"
    using TemperatureSensor = TemperatureSensorPlatformA;

#elsif PLATFORM_B
    #include "TemperatureSensorPlatformB.hpp"
    using TemperatureSensor = TemperatureSensorPlatformB;
#endif
```

This keeps the `ifdef's` in one place and removes most of the boiler plate. Of course pimpl can still be useful for other reasons - like hiding implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Barring further clarification, there are two ways to interpret the use of the term "hardware-dependent" that will inform the desired design choice:

### Same Sensor, Different Platform

**Goal:** Given this interpretation, the goal is to make sure that the temperature sensor driver code (i.e. piece of software that performs the communications with and interpretation of data from the sensor) is designed in a fashion such that it can function across different microcontroller ("MCU") vendors and architectures.

**Design:** The best way to approach this problem is to identify which aspects of the sensor driver code vary between MCUs? Only two things come to mind:

1. Native data types (i.e. word = 8-bits/16-bits/32-bits?)
2. Transport layer (i.e. SPI or I2C peripheral architecture and drivers)

Point 1 is easily remedied by ensuring that you always use fixed-width data primitive types (e.g. `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int`). Point 2 can be addressed in a number of ways, including conditional compiling described in the question and mortenvp's answer.

However, the cleanest and most flexible way would be through Policy-Based Design as it will enable us to extract all of the platform-specific transport logic into a separate class that is injected into the sensor driver class as a template parameter. Now to support a new platform, you just need to implement the platform-specific transport policy class, keeping the sensor driver business logic untouched (i.e. no (re-)introduction of bugs).

The platform-specific transport policies:

```cpp
/* In stm32_spi_transport.hpp */
class STM32_SPI {
    uint32_t read() { /* STM32-specific SPI read logic */ }
};

/* In stm32_i2c_transport.hpp */
class STM32_I2C {
    uint32_t read() { /* STM32-specific I2C read logic */ }
};

/* In pic_spi_transport.hpp */
class PIC_SPI {
    uint32_t read() { /* PIC-specific SPI read logic */ }
};
```

The invariant sensor driver and application

```cpp
/* In temp_sensor.hpp */
template<typename TTransport>
class TempSensor {
private:
    TTransport& transport_;
public:
    TempSensor(const TTransport& t) : transport_{t} { }

    float getTemp() { return convert(transport_.read()); }

private:
    float convert(uint32_t raw_val) {
        return raw_val * 2.3; /* for simplicity */
    }
};

/* In main.cpp */
int main()
{
    STM32_SPI transport{}; /* If STM32 SPI */
    /* or */
    STM32_I2C transport{}; /* If STM32 I2C */
    /* or */
    PIC_SPI   transport{}; /* Or if PIC */

    /* Stays constant */
    TempSensor sensor{transport};
    float temp = sensor.getTemp();

    return 0;
}
```

### Same Platform, Different Sensor

**Goal:** Given this interpretation, the goal is to make sure that the temperature sensor driver code can support different versions of the sensor.

**Design:** This needs further clarification as there are two ways to take this:

1. Completely *unrelated* sensors (e.g. analog thermistor from Analog Devices or a digital thermocouple from TI).
2. Different version of *the same sensor* (e.g. 8-bit or 10-bit readout)

Point 1 is really only best addressed by making sure that the driver classes expose the same interface, such that the application code can treat them in the same way (e.g. create each like `sensor = AnalogThermistor();` or `sensor = SPIThermocouple();` but interact with both like `val = sensor.getTemp();`). Point 2, however, is best addressed by some form of compile-time conditionals.

Conditional compilation would only take place in the few places that deal with the hardware differences in the sensor variants -- like in the `convert()` where you translate the raw bits into a floating point temperature value. If you have access to C++17, then `if constexpr()` is the best way to achieve this, otherwise I would suggest preprocessor `#ifdef`s. But again, in this scenario they will be neatly localized and confined.